# Safari on Mac doesn't allow to enable my extension

Tags: safari, safari-web-extension

I develop an extension for Safari on Mac. I test situation when extension is disabled, so I uncheck(disable) it in Safari Preferences, but cannot check(enable) it again. Safari shows me message:

> **Safari detected an app or service that interfered with clicking.**
>
> To protect your privacy and security, this extension was not turned
> on. After quitting the app or service, you can try to turn on this
> extension again.

[Safari message][1]

Please help to understand the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an application that is adding some sort of overlay over the entire screen. In my case, it was QuickShade application.

After disabling it, i was able to enable the safari extensions.

I suggest you disable or close any application that is adding an overlay or any assistive applications and try again

Comment: In my case it was Zoom.app!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - After searching high and low for a solution to this problem, I've found one that worked for me. On macOS Ventura 13.4
Go to System Settings > Network > Firewall.
Firewall was turned off for me.
Turn on Firewall and leave all default settings.
Immediately turn Firewall back off.
Go back to the Extension menu in Safari (Safari > Settings > Extensions) and try to enable the extension(s) again.
This time it worked.
There was no need to boot into Safe Mode or reinstall the extension.
The extensions in question for me were Adblock Engine and Adblock Icon.
I hope others can get this to work with this method.